# Cascading addition of records in CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

there are 2 entities
parental

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.add( phone );
        phone.setPerson( this );
    }

    public void removePhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.remove( phone );
        phone.setPerson( null );
    }
}
```

and children

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
...
```

Direct cascading addition of records does not work

```
Person person = new Person("Rodber Smit");
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
  person.addPhone(new Phone(0l,"xxx" + i,person));
}

person = personRepository.save(person);
```

An exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: io.khasang.moikaplus.entity.Phone;
```

is thrown.
Have to write and read the parent record again.

```
person = personRepository.save(person);
person = personRepository.findOne(person.getId());
```

Whether it is possible to avoid two additional read and write operations?

Comment: I'm not sure, but, please, try to do not set id for a newly create `Phone`.
`new Phone(null, "xxx" + i,person)`

Comment: I can not believe it, but it seems your advice worked :-). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its expected, when you try to cascade object that has an id, hibernate will consider the object to be persisted but since it is not managed it will be dealt with as detached object, what you need to do is to not set the Id and the cascade should work well.